# How to turn off data roaming in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios

I find the new iOS 7 toggles to be a bit ambiguous.  If I want to turn **off** data roaming do I leave it so that the button is to the left (only white) or do it push it to the right (where the color green appears on the left of the button).

In case you're wondering why I find it confusing: I can interpret it as "yes, I want to turn data roaming off" -- in which case I would slide the button to the right. Or I could just read it as "Data Roaming" and deactivate it by sliding it to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enable `Data Roaming` when showing the green part to the left.

On iOS 6 and older you had the text ON or OFF on the button. OFF disabled `Data Roaming`, and ON enabled `Data Roaming` and the button was showing a blue background behind the ON. So on iOS 7 you have the same behavior - just without the ON/OFF text, and with a green background - you can however turn on an `1` as ON and a `0` as OFF under `Settings=>General=>Accessibility=>On/Off Labels`)

Answer (score 0):

The button turned to the right showing a green color means that "Yes Data roaming is On" and the other way means "Data Roaming off"

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I've just had the same problem and this indicators are confusing !

If you goto Settings->General->Accessibility->On/Off Labels and enable that, it makes it "a little clearer".